# SonarQube giving unused private method issue for lambda usage

Tags: java, lambda, sonarqube

I have the following logic;

```
..
if(list.stream()
       .filter(MyClass::isEnabled)
       .filter(this::isActive)
       .count() > 0) {
    //do smth
}
..
private boolean isActive(MyClass obj) {
    return bool;
}
```

As you see, `isActive` method is being used in the stream structure, but when I build this class on Jenkins, I get the unused private method issue from SonarQube, it says you should delete this redundant private method. Is this a bug? If not, why haven't they still included lambda logic in their analyze structure?

Only solution is, obviously, to do this;

`.filter(obj -> isActive(obj))`, but it destroys the uniformity, and even the readability (imo).

Comment: Strange. Lambdas seem to be okay because it seems to accept `MyClass::isEnabled` which is a method reference. Try the `className::instanceMethod` route where `className` is the name of the class in which `isActive`, i.e. `instanceMethod = isActive` is defined.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a known issue of SonarQube java analyzer : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-583

This is due to a lack of semantic analysis to resolve properly method reference (thus identify to which method this::isActive refers to).